# How can I programmatically get the list of frameworks and libraries included in an ios project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am trying to get the list of all the libraries and frameworks included in an ios project, programmatically using Objective-C and send the list to the server. How to get this list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [NSBundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle)

> [+allFrameworks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/allFrameworks)
>   Returns an array of all of the application’s
>   bundles that represent frameworks.

**Declaration**

```
//SWIFT 
class func allFrameworks() -> [AnyObject]

//OBJECTIVE-C
+ (NSArray *)allFrameworks
```

**Return Value**

An array of all of the application’s bundles that represent frameworks. Only frameworks with one or more Objective-C classes in them are included.

**Discussion**

The returned array includes frameworks that are linked into an application when the application is built and bundles for frameworks that have been dynamically created.

**Import Statement**

import Foundation

**Availability**

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @Ajith ...
Also, I see that an array of NSBundles is returned by this method
Is there a way where we can search for a specific framework in the array returned, for example if I want to find out if CoreLocation is included in the project?
Thanks!

Comment: @auditya 
`for (NSBundle *framework in [NSBundle allFrameworks])  NSLog(@"%@",framework.bundlePath.lastPathComponent);` 
and compare it with `@"CoreLocation.framework"`

Comment: that works! Also, I found a different way for it earlier by using the bundle's bundleIdentifier... Its value is "com.apple.corelocation" for the corelocation framework.

Comment: Is it also possible to figure out where a framework is being referred to in the application?

Comment: @prabodhprakash Removing the framework temporarily should definitely show you some errors/warnings, right?